# Four-by-four table with equal row and column products

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, calculation-puzzle

Is there a way of filling a 4×4 table with 16 distinct integers from 1, 2, ..., 100 such that the products of the numbers in every row and in every column are all equal to each other?

Comment: The largest prime number that could be in the table is 23.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Notice that each row and each column contains the numbers 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

$$ \begin{array}{ a b c d }
  4*7 & 1*6 & 3*1 & 2*5 & \\
  3*5 & 2*1 & 4*6 & 1*7 &\\
  1*1 & 4*5 & 2*7 & 3*6 &\\
  2*6 & 3*7 & 1*5 & 4*1 &\\
\end{array} $$